# I have a file which contains a table comprised of coordinates of x and y of a rectangle:

Tags: python, file

```
2  -5
-2  4
5   6
0   0
-4  12
14   6
3   -1
7   -9
8   15
-6  -3
2   5
1   6
-2  3
-4  0
7   1
3  -2
2  -2
1   3
0   8
```

How can I obtain coordinates of the smallest rectangle in another file?

Comment: These look like a list of numbers, please explain *how* we can parse the coordinates from this list.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: @Rihana Please share the expected output based on the sample input you posted.

Comment: *What* other file?  What does that file have to do with this list of numbers?  How are these numbers the coordinates of a rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to generate a list of all combinations of two points in the file, filter out those that have the same `x` or `y` coordinates since they don't form rectangles, and then use `min` with a key function that returns the area of the rectangle formed by a given pair of points to find the smallest rectangle that can be formed by the points in the list:

```
from itertools import combinations
with open('points.txt') as f:
    print(min([((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in combinations([tuple(map(int, l.split())) for l in f], 2) if x1 != x2 and y1 != y2], key=lambda p: abs((p[1][0] - p[0][0]) * (p[1][1] - p[0][1]))))
```

Given your sample input, this outputs:

```
((3, -1), (2, -2))
```